# Node.js server perform GET request on itself every minute

Tags: node.js, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have set up an AWS EC2 instance with Linux and using Node.js to run my server. I write some code to check the ip address of request like this:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {

  var ip = req.connection.remoteAddress;

  console.log('ip: ' + ip);

  res.render('index');
});
```

Then I check the log in EC2 located at `{project_location}/log/node.stdout.log`. Every minute I got an ip (127.0.0.1) to access application:

[image]

Because I found this document:

> **Status Checks for Your Instances**
>
> tl;dr
>
> Status checks are performed every minute and each returns a pass or a
>   fail status.
>   (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-system-instance-status-check.html?icmpid=docs_ec2_console)

Why is there a GET request from 127.0.0.1 every minute?

Comment: Its not clear to me how a web server heartbeat is on-topic here. Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Sorry about bad question and I understand it. Thank you very much!